# How to remove the projectile project name after the file name

Tags: projectile, mode-line

I am attempting to clean up my modeline due to overcrowding. In my quest I have come across a problem I cannot figure out, namely projectile.

By this I mean the project name after the file name, it appends [project-name] after the file name.

example (if I was too vague):

> -U:---/path/to/file[project-name] (modes) etc...

I have checked the customize projectile group and the readme on the github repo, but to no avail. Is there any other way I can remove this?

Comment: You want to `grep` for `projectile-project-name` and `mode-line` -- perhaps you have something like `'(:propertize (:eval (when (ignore-errors (projectile-project-root)) (concat " " (projectile-project-name)))))`.  It might be set to a variable, or it could be directly in the `mode-line-format`.   I'm just guessing based on the first Google I tried with some keywords like:  **projctile project name mode-line emacs**  In this example, you might want to remove `(concat " " (projectile-project-name))` if the project-name is not particularly useful to you in the mode-line.

Comment: Never mind, I found the root of the problem. if you set variable Projectile Mode Line in customize or edit the variable directly in the emacs configuration file to nil, both the lighter and the [project-name] disappear, thanks (I would upvote your comment but I haven't got enough points yet)

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE! Please post the solution to your problem as an answer. You will be able to [self-accept](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) after 48 hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind, I found the root of the problem. if you set variable Projectile Mode Line in customize or edit the variable directly in the emacs configuration file to nil, both the lighter and the [project-name] disappear.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiminishedModes is your friend.

It hides the minor and eventually the major move that you don't want to be displayed in your mode-line.